# Having trouble finding/searching for links and saving them to a list variable through python/selenium

Tags: python

Practicing web scraping through selenium by opening user's dating profiles through a dating site. I need selenium to save a href link for every profile on the page but unfortunately it only saves the first profile on the list, rather than creating a list variable with all the links saved. All of the profiles start with the same two div class/style which is "member-thumbnail" and "position: absolute". Thank you for any help that you can offer.

Here is the html code:

```
<div class="member-thumbnail">
    <div style="position: absolute;">
        <a href="/Member/Details/LvL-Up">
        <img src="//storage.com/imgcdn/m/t/502b24cb-3f75-49a1-a61a-ae80e18d86a0" class="presenceLine online">
        </a>
    </div>    
</div>
```

Here is my code:

```
link_list = browser.find_elements_by_css_selector('.member-thumbnail a')
for element in linklist:
    browser.get(element.get_attribute('href'))
```

Here is the error message I receive:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\artur\Desktop\feabie.py", line 31, in <module>
    browser.get(element.get_attribute('href'))
  File "C:\Users\artur\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 139, in get_attribute
    attributeValue = self.parent.execute_script(
  File "C:\Users\artur\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 634, in execute_script
    return self.execute(command, {
  File "C:\Users\artur\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Users\artur\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.StaleElementReferenceException: Message: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Selenium doesn't keep `urls` but `WebElements` which are "refereces" to elements on current page. If you use `get()` to load new page then it loses these references.

You have to get all links as strings before you will use them with `get()`

```
link_list = browser.find_elements_by_css_selector('.member-thumbnail a')

all_links = []

for element in link_list:
    all_links.append(element.get_attribute('href'))

for url in all_links:
    browser.get(url)
```

Comment: Your code works but there are two links that are given for each user's profile within the profile search in the html code. One links to their profile from the profile image, another links to their profile from their username. With the code that you posted, it saves both the image link and the username link and when it is run it views each profile twice. Any ideas on how to have it just grab one of the links in order to not view each profile twice? Thank you.

Comment: use better selector. Maybe there is class, ID or tag which can better select items. OR if you always get two links then get only `odd` or `even` elements from list - ie. `all_links[0::2]` or `all_links[1::2]`

Comment: Thank you! Using your latter solution.